# Pre-Login Handshake Error Connecting to SQL Server 2012 through VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, handshake

So I'm simply trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 instance running on a local server running Windows Server 2012 through Visual Studio 2012's SQL Server Object Explorer. I can connect to it through other computers, locally and remotely, perfectly fine, but for some reason my desktop gives me this lovely error:

"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258) - The wait operation timed out."

I'm using SQL Server Authentication in SS2012, unencrypted, etc. I'm really not sure what information to include, I'm sure it's some stupid issue, but for the life of me I can't find a solution. All searches give me a bunch of old as hell results.

Comment: Have a look in the SQL server error log, you may find other useful related errors in there that may explain more, the errors returned to the client are usually not the whole story.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Fully qualified domain name?

Looks like a DNS issue